# Is the exterior algebra a universal enveloping superalgebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra, superalgebra, lie-superalgebras

Let $V$ be a vector space and $\Lambda(V)$ the exterior algebra of $V$. Is $\Lambda(V)$ the universal enveloping superalgebra of some Lie superalgebra? If so, which?